# Cliping roads based on shapefile in Python

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas

I have shp file of [Wrocław city borders](http://geoportal.wroclaw.pl/www/pliki/osiedla/granice-osiedli.zip) and [Wroclaw bicycle paths](http://geoportal.wroclaw.pl/www/pliki/DaneRowerowe/TrasyRowerowe.zip). I would like to calculate how many km of bicycle paths are in each district.

To calculate that I wanted to select only paths that are in each district, and then sum the lengths of them. I have tried doing it in 4 ways, and failed. For ease of the example, lets use only first district

```
import geopandas as gpd

#For ease of the example, lets use only first district
district = city_bounderies.iloc[[0], ]
type(district)

#we can see that there are some bicycle paths in this district
plot = district.plot( color = "red")
bicycle_path.plot(ax = plot)

#for example bicycle path 8982 id in the district
plot = district.plot( color = "red")
bicycle_path.iloc[[8982],].plot(ax = plot)
```

**1. geopandas within method - based on what I read [here](https://michelleful.github.io/code-blog/2015/04/29/geopandas-manipulation/)**

`district_bicycle_path = bicycle_path[bicycle_path.geometry.within(district)]`

but I get empty dataframe as a result

**2. geopandas clip method - based on what I read [here](https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/use-data-open-source-python/intro-vector-data-python/vector-data-processing/clip-vector-data-in-python-geopandas-shapely/)**

`bicycle_path.clip(district)` 
`district.clip(bicycle_path)`

But they both give error:
`# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'LineString'`

**3. geopandas erase method - based on what I read [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216439/clip-hole-into-shapefile/302015#302015)**

`bicycle_path.Erase(district)`

But that gives error: 
`#error AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'Erase'`

**4. geopandas function overlay**

`gpd.overlay(district, bicycle_path, how='intersection')`

Error:
`#error TypeError: overlay only takes GeoDataFrames with (multi)polygon  geometries.`

## EDIT:

I am adding smaller, reproducible example, based on [description how to create shp](https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/CSC/notebooks/L2/geopandas-basics.html#Creating-geometries-into-a-GeoDataFrame)

Initial dataset looks something like that

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, LineString

# Create an empty geopandas GeoDataFrame
Sample_district = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
Sample_line = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
# Create a new column called 'geometry' to the GeoDataFrame
Sample_district['geometry'] = None
Sample_line['geometry'] = None
# Coordinates of the sample data
coordinates_district = [(0, 0), (2, 0), (2, 2), (0, 2)]
coordinates_bicycleroad = [(-1, 1), (3, 1)]
# Create a Shapely polygon from the coordinate-tuple list
poly = Polygon(coordinates_district)
line = LineString(coordinates_bicycleroad)
# Insert the polygon into 'geometry' -column at index 0
Sample_district.loc[0, 'geometry'] = poly
Sample_line.loc[0, 'geometry'] = line

#Plot
p = Sample_district.plot(color = "blue")
Sample_line.plot(ax = p, color = "red")
```

Which gives plot
[image]

But I would like to remove all the bicycle roads that are outside the district, to look something like that:

```
Sample_line_desired = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
Sample_line_desired['geometry'] = None
coordinates_bicycleroad_desired = [(0, 1), (2, 1)]
line_desired = LineString(coordinates_bicycleroad_desired)
Sample_line_desired.loc[0, 'geometry'] = line_desired

p = Sample_district.plot(color = "blue")
Sample_line_desired.plot(ax = p, color = "black")
```

[image]

Comment: it's impossible to help you without a runnable example. Mock up some very simple geometries (straight lines, squares and triangles) and see if your code works

Comment: @PaulH The original data are in the links provided. I can also prepare artificial sample data later in the day

Comment: @PaulH I edited the question and added the runnable example with some very simple geometries

Comment: One common reason for getting no data after a scoping operation (clip or within) is that the two geodataframes don't have the same Coordinate Reference System (CRS).   So before you do either of those operations, make sure they have matching CRS, and if not, re-project one to the others to make them match.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `shapely.ops.split()` function. Following your code to generate initial data set:

```py
from shapely.ops import split
spl = split(poly, line)
```

gives
[image]